# Upload multiple files in one request to AWS S3 from Laravel / PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently using the standard Laravel file storage to upload a single file to S3 but now have a need to upload a whole load of separate files at once (possibly up to 200). I want to do this as efficiently as possible, rather than using separate requests. Is this possible somehow, either using Laravel storage, the Flysystem library it's based on or the official Amazon S3 PHP SDK? Separate files are very small, about 1Kb each.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how you can pass a list of multiple files to a controller for uploading or how to upload multiple files at once from the controller to S#?

Comment: @Josh the latter - I'm asking what the AWS S3 PHP calls or code are to upload multiple files in one hit rather than many separate requests. Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything in Laravel Filesystem however you could look at the AWS S3 API and see if there is a way there. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html